# Send HIPAA compliant mails in Salesforce

Tags: apex, email, sales

One of our clients in CS is a Health Care Company that have many clinics arround US. They want to be able to send HIPAA complaint mails from Salesforce to their contacts, my question is if we can achieve this without the use of an App in Appexchange or which App we can recommend to the client?

Thanks.

Comment: IANAL, but reading a bit through a summary-of-HIPAA site, hhttps://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/security/laws-regulations/index.html, it *seems* relatively straightforward to me - encrypt your emails, make sure they're sent to the actual patients, and only let a patient's feed be seen by their doctor (or whoever else counts as "authorized"). All of that can be done in Salesforce without needing something from the AppExchange so far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are:

- Use an AppExchange product, e.g [Cloud Maven powered by PauBox](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000H0A2eUAF)
- Use Email relay (say, between SFDC and Gmail) and have Gmail integrated with a secure email vendor such as Mimecast, Virtru, etc.  Using rules, you can configure it so that all outbound email is sent to the secure vendor's storage or only selected emails (e.g. subject line contains `Confidential`)
- SFDC doesn't have a native secure email solution

Comment: [Encryption isn't required by HIPAA](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/2001/is-the-use-of-encryption-mandatory-in-the-security-rule/index.html). You probably know how "secure" email products work - they verify your identity via one-time passcode sent to email or SMS, then let you see the email. Thus, there's no need to send an email from Salesforce. Sending a "you have mail" and let them access the "body" (content) hosted in Salesforce is enough. But then you probably need Shield for at-rest to be on the safe side and that'll cost more than some AppExchange plugin

Comment: @identigral -- right; the encryption (at least for Mimecast) is at rest on their server. Edited answer